# Calling ADODB inside a function?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering why when i put an sql [ADODB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adodb/) query in side a function it produces the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object in -path to script-
```

My function is something like:

```
$dsn = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/db'; 
$db = ADONewConnection($dsn);

function getem($q){
$r=$db->Execute($q);
return $r->RecordCount();
}

echo getem("select * from table");
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Variable Scope Issue**

You need to import `$db` instance into your function using `global` keyword:

```
function getem($q){
  global $db;

  $r=$db->Execute($q);
  return $r->RecordCount();
}
```

That should do the trick.

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Not sure why it didn't make it for me :(

Comment: @David: Was instance created fine? `var_dump($db);`

Answer (score 2):

[variable scope issue](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

inside the function, the local variables of `$db` is not defined

ugly fix is to use global like

```
function getem($q)
{
  global $db;
  $r=$db->Execute($q);
  return $r->RecordCount();
}
```

Or you can consider wrap the adodb as static class like

```
class db
{
  protected static $db;

  public static function execute($query)
  {
    if (!self::$db)  // or check object instance type
    {
      self::$db = ADONewConnection('mysql://user:pass@localhost/db');
    }

    return self::$db->execute($query);
  }
}

function getem($q)
{
  $r=db::execute($q);
  return $r->RecordCount();
}
```